# Are there any shudra philosophers in the advaita school?

Tags: advaita, shudra

I have seen Shudra Philosophers in the Dvaita school mainly in Madhva Sampradaya
Like Purandara Dasa .
But I did not see any Shudra philosophers  in  Advaita school.
So are there any such Shudra philosophers belonging to the Advaita school?

Comment: Hello Vishnu Its Kanakadasa not purandara dasa  he had learnt vedas and created sangeeta ragas. Lot many are there in saivat schools

Comment: Sorryi thick it Is purandara dasa

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about dvaita but actually deciding caste based system of hinduism the questionnaire is christian agenda driven